# Query field if empty

Tags: php, mysql

What should be the logic for the function below?

```
function check_empty($field){
  $this->_params();
  $db = $this->getDb();
  $milestone = $db->select()
    ->from('milestone')
    ->where("$field IN ('')")
    ->where("name = ?", $this->milestone['name']);

  $milestone_stmt = $db->query($milestone);
  echo $milestone->__toString();
  $milestone_result = $milestone_stmt->fetchAll();

  if(count($milestone_result) > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is the function used to check if a field is empty. If the field is originally field and updated with the contents removed in a form the other function should insert a form
but it is not inserting.

Comment: I am just new. That is why. I am also in the field.

Comment: Nope i meant that you have asked 6 questions, but you haven't accepted any of answers. On the top-left of every answers, you have `tick` icon. Click there if you think that was the right answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will return true if it can't match any rows, false otherwise:

```
function check_empty($field) {
    $this->_params();
    $db = $this->getDb();
    $milestone = $db->select()
                    ->from('milestone')
                    ->where("$field = ''")
                    ->where("name = ?", $this->milestone['name']);
    $milestone_stmt = $db->query($milestone);

    //No query results means the field is not empty.
    return $milestone_stmt === false;
}
```

Comment: Will there be a possibility that there is a result which is not null or a special character or something?

Comment: @efox it'll either be a statement or false. The expression `milestone_stmt === false` will return `false` if `$milestone_stmt` is anything other than false